# what is this egyptian-themed scary movie from the 80s?

Tags: identify-this-movie

This is one I vaguely remember from my childhood. I only remember a couple scenes. I think there was an archaeologist exploring some pyramid ruins in the desert, and maybe unlocking a curse of some kind. One scene I remember (this is going to sound odd, and I am maybe not remembering accurately): a character is in a vehicle (maybe a jeep or truck) in the desert; he removes the cigarette lighter, and sand begins blowing out of it, burying the guy and the vehicle.

Another scene was under the pyramid, I think, and near the end; there was a river or waterway with a boat and a gate across the water; I think this was near the end and going thru the gate took them to an underworld kind of place.

Comment: Can you tell us about the film? Language, country of origin,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Dr. Phibes Rises Again](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Phibes_Rises_Again) seems likely. It specifically is a horror movie and has an underground river with a gate across it that the villain escapes down at the end.  It is also old enough (1972) to match the time frame.

**Edit**: It also contains the scene where sand comes bursting out of a cigeratte lighter socket in a jeep in the middle of the desert, turning the victim into a skeleton. The aftermath appears in the trailer around the 1 minute mark:

Comment: Hmmf, beat me to it. ;) Hope you don't mind the edit. +1

Comment: No problem. I was on my phone and it was the best I could do.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks! That is pretty impressive that you could identify it.  wow does it look cheesy now

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [*Stargate* (1994)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_%28film%29), starring Kurt Russell.

Neither of the details you mention are in the movie. However, you may just be mis-remembering them. In Stargate there is a LOT of sand, and stuff gets buried. Also, the Stargate itself is buried, so it has to be dug out. As for the "underground" scenes, there are numerous scenes that take place inside the pyramid and temple which, in a dim memory, might seem to be "underground".

Also, in terms of scary Egyptian movies, Stargate is the only one I know of from the 1980-2000 period, except for The Mummy (1999) which is too late for your time scale, and The Mummy does not have as much sand in it.

Comment: You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.

Comment: So... it's not from the 80s and none of the specific scenes match?... And *Stargate* isn't a "scary movie". I don't see how this fits.

Comment: To a kid, Stargate is definitely scary. I was in my 20s and I still thought it was scary. Also, the "feel" of the question is just like Stargate. Notice how he uses the words "unlock" and "gate". That is what the whole movie is about, the team trying to unlock the Stargate.